# Changing Coder for a transform with a backwards compatible coder

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to figure out how to swap out a Coder(StringUtf8Coder) for a custom implementation.

I have implemented a coder that is adds the ability to handle snappy compressed strings:

```
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.Coder;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderException;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.DelegateCoder;
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import org.xerial.snappy.Snappy;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CompressedByteArrayCoder extends DelegateCoder<String, byte[]> {

    private static String decompressSnappy(byte[] input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null) {
            throw new CoderException("null input is not accepted");
        }
        if (Snappy.isValidCompressedBuffer(input)) {
            return Snappy.uncompressString(input);
        }
        return new String(input, Charsets.UTF_8);
    }

    private static byte[] compressSnappy(String input) throws IOException {
        return Snappy.compress(input);
    }

    public static CompressedByteArrayCoder of() {
        return new CompressedByteArrayCoder(ByteArrayCoder.of(), CompressedByteArrayCoder::compressSnappy, CompressedByteArrayCoder::decompressSnappy);
    }

    private CompressedByteArrayCoder(Coder<byte[]> coder, CodingFunction<String, byte[]> toFn, CodingFunction<byte[], String> fromFn) {
        super(coder, toFn, fromFn);
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out a way to swap out the StringUtf8Coder (the default for PubSubIO.Read) in a way that does not cause dataflow pipeline update to fail.

I am trying to figure out how to tell the dataflow service runner that the two coders are "compatible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PCollection's coders cannot be changed when updating a running pipeline on the Google Cloud Dataflow service at this time. In this case, you'd have to submit the pipeline as a new Dataflow job.

See [Updating an Existing Pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline) for more information, particularly section about compatibility check.

This is something we might address in the future, however. Please check our documentation for any updates.